# 16.04 - Ubuntu can't connect to ad-hoc network

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, adhoc

I set up an ad-hoc network on a 16.04 Ubuntu machine, to which I used to connect from a 14.04 laptop.

I now changed my laptop and installed 16.04, and I am now unable to connect to that same network, despite having the exact same network configuration (from network manager GUI). The network is detected but it just looks like it's trying to connect forever.

I also tried setting my laptop's IP address to static from `/etc/network/interfaces`, but as soon as I connected to the network with the GUI, it hangs again and my wifi adapter disappears from `ifconfig` output until I stop the connection attempt.

According to `lspci`, my network controller is `Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)`.

Did anything change in 16.04's network management that could explain such a behaviour? Any help is very welcome.